# I've received error "uninitialized constant ContactsController"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a form page, but keep getting the issue when I try and run the program. Using Ruby On Rails.

`routes.rb` is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root to: 'pages#home'
    get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
    get 'signup', to: 'pages#signup'
    resources :contacts
end
```

`contacts_controller` is:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end
end
```

What's the issue?

Comment: Make sure that the file is not misspelled. Should just be `contacts_controller.rb`

Comment: @Ricks Thanks! I'll check it out. It's spelt 'contacts_controllers.rb', maybe it could be that?

Comment: @RickS you're a life saver! That was the issue. I owe you

Comment: minor suggestion - change formatting of your file, from tabs to 2 spaces

Answer (score 0):

So normally if you get that error, it means you have a typo either in the file name or the class name at the top of the file.
So try to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file is not misspelled. Should just be `contacts_controller.rb`